# Why I can't substitute the values ​of variables in the query update parameter findOneAndUpdate() / updateOne()?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to do one method for updating different parameters in MongoDB, using mongoose. But the update field cannot be passed in the variable for some reason. Are there any tips to do this?

```js
const updateCurrentUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { token, valToUpdate, newVal } = req.body;
    const id = jwt.verify(token, secretWord).userId;
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: { valToUpdate: newVal } }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`errror: ${err}`)
        }
        else {
            console.log(`resss: ${res}`)
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a computed property key (note that this doesn't work in older JS versions) to achieve dynamic properties:

```
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: { [valToUpdate]: newVal } }, (err, res) => {
```

Alternatively, use the bracket notation:

```
const updateObject = {}
updateObject[valToUpdate] = newVal
User.findOneAndUpdate(..., {$set: updateObject},...)
```